# Getting the id of a checked checkbox on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've done some looking around at various examples and options and I've managed to stump myself and wondered if anyone could please help?.

I have a few rows pulled from a table that have a radio button within the row and an id (dynamic), which i wouldn't know as this is the row concatenated with 0 or 1 for show and hide. Below the radio buttons are additional information fields for each choice which match the id of the radio button later. These boxes the user can enter some text. When these fields are checked, the idea is the box is visible for them to add the info and hidden when unselected. The checked boxes work fine, all selected rows show a tick. I am using the same form to create and edit entries.

When a user selects an option and it is saved, on the edit page, the page loads and the checkbox is checked but i need that id of the checkbox to display or hide the row below it. As I don't know these ids, I can't get jQuery to grab it as they'll change and are dynamic.

What I want to do is on page load, grab the selected checkbox ids and then i can use those to show or hide the text boxes below.

Do anyone have any ideas of how precisely I can do this.

Many thanks in advance and sorry to have been initially vague.

Relevant code is...

```
<div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Here are your work experience placements</label>
        <div class="row"><!--Start of row -->
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="table-responsive">
              <table class="table table-bordered">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="col">Business name</th>
                      <th scope="col">Address</th>
                      <th scope="col">Dates</th>
                      <th scope="col">Include on CV</th>
                      <th scope="col">Exclude from CV</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                                              <tr>
                          <td>Bolton College</td>
                          <td>Deane Road, Bolton, BL3 5BG </td>
                          <td>18/05/2018 to 18/05/2018</td>
                          <td><input type="radio" name="placement_id_0" id="we_check_13_1" value="13_1" onclick=" checkInclude(this.id);" checked/>

                          <td><input type="radio" name="placement_id_0" id="we_uncheck_13_0" onclick=" checkInclude(this.id);" value="13_0"/></td>
                        </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>  
          </div>
      </div> <!--End of row -->


      <!--Work experience descriptins start here -->
      <div class="row"><!--Start of row -->
          <div class="col-md-12">
          <h3>Work experience descriptions</h3>
          <p class="lead">Please complete the brief descriptions of your roles at each of your work experience placements</p>
          <hr/>

          <div id='we_div_13'>
            <p>What did you do at Bolton College between 18/05/2018 and 18/05/2018?</p>
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="10" id='description_13' name="we_desc_13" value="251" placeholder="Please detail your role and describe specifically what you did whilst on placement at Bolton College during that time period"></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>

            </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Some sample HTML/code would be useful...

Comment: Read how to create a **[mcve]**.  What you ask for is pretty straight-forward, but we'll need something to work with (please don't just copy/paste a load of your code - just give us the relevant parts)

Comment: You don't need the ID's, you can use something like `.closest()` to select the nearest element without knowing the ID's. Cant help you anymore than that without seeing your HTML markup

Answer (score 2):

When your table completed rendering, try to run this function:

```
// Get all input box elements
var boxes = $("input[type='checkbox']");
// Loop through each input box
$.each( boxes, function( key, value ) {
    // Check if the input box is checked
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        // Input box is checked - Add anything you want to happen in the clause below
        var boxid = $(this).attr('id')
        console.log(boxid + ' is checked');
    } else {
        // Input box is not checked - Add anything you want to happen in the clause below
        var boxid = $(this).attr('id')
        console.log(boxid + ' is not checked');
    }
});
```

On another note, the second way to do it is by making the function server side by adding a condition when you bring the data in that if the following table column or object contains data or is null to do something; the above JS will identify all checked and unchecked items client side, I guess your question was how to identify if a box is checked; this should easily do it.

Comment: Thanks so much. I'll try that. jQuery is still a learning curve for me.

Comment: Welcome, it's pretty easy; I'm sure you'll figure it out. JQ is very powerful; you can do a lot with it, trial & error you'll nail it down.

Comment: Thanks again. Yes, very powerful. Only really used the most basic aspects but i'm getting there. Many thanks. Appreciate your time!